# How to get existing repository files on Local PC using GIT?

Tags: git, github

I made a repository few months ago for one of my jquery plugins. But recently I had to format my PC for some issues. So now I re-installed GIT but I am not quite used to with GIT. 
I followed some tutorial last time to setup the repository and kept committing for updated file. But now I want to know how can I get the GIT configured and fetch all the files of my jQuery plugin project back to my local system, so that I can continue working for the updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log back into github.com.  Navigate to your repository.  The GIT URL is usually located right underneath the project description.  From there it's just "git clone URL".  That is:

```
git clone https://github.com/<your account name>/<your project name>.git
```

And if I'm not mistaken, [here](https://github.com/aslamdoctor/jQuery.mapmarker) is your project page.  Such that this is EXACTLY what you need to type:

```
git clone https://github.com/aslamdoctor/jQuery.mapmarker.git
```

Comment: Thanks but that is not my repo. Anyway i will try with mine and update u.

Comment: Oops, wrong Aslam. "git clone https://github.com/aslamdoctor/jQuery.mapmarker.git"  That should do it.

Comment: Thanks and i can run this command from any directory and it will load the files there right?

Comment: Yes, it will create a sub-directory for you from where you typed "git clone"

Comment: one more thing, I tried the command but I think im missing some configuration in my git installation as I am getting authentication error. it is saying "permission denied(pubic key)". can you help me with that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Selbie got you the right clone command, but you either haven't installed your public key on github, or it has changed.  While you could clone from a read-only URL, it's better to go ahead and fix this since it will need to be fixed before you can push any changes.

Login to github and go to "Account Settings" (icon in the upper-right corner).  Click on "Add SSH keys."  Now paste the contents of your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or `~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` depending on which one you have.  If you don't have that directory, you can use this tutorial for how to generate keys:

[Github SSH key generation tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)

If you use Windows, there are multiple methods of generating keys, depending on what software you use.  However, make sure whatever you use generates keys in OpenSSH format.  For example, in Putty, you have to export the key to OpenSSH format to use it with github.